# Create key for duplicate values and single value in an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

This array type of out I required.

```
Array
(
[2018-03-25] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [loyalty_transcation_id] => 33
            [user_id] => 58
            [bill_copy_image_path] => 03252018_182712.jpg
            [create_date] => 2018-03-25 19:27:12
            [name] => bernd koch
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [loyalty_transcation_id] => 3
            [user_id] => 21
            [bill_copy_image_path] => 09132017_044456.jpg
            [create_date] => 2018-03-25 05:44:56
            [name] => Rahul Upadhyay
        )

)

[2017-09-27] => Array

(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [loyalty_transcation_id] => 10
            [user_id] => 24
            [bill_copy_image_path] => 09272017_115913.jpg
            [create_date] => 2017-09-27 12:59:13
            [name] => raj@ot.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [loyalty_transcation_id] => 3
            [user_id] => 21
            [bill_copy_image_path] => 09132017_044456.jpg
            [create_date] => 2017-09-27 05:44:56
            [name] => Rahul Upadhyay
        )

)

[2017-09-28] => Array

(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [loyalty_transcation_id] => 10
            [user_id] => 24
            [bill_copy_image_path] => 09272017_115913.jpg
            [create_date] => 2017-09-28 12:59:13
            [name] => raj@ot.com
        )

)
```

I want to save all data using date as key and if one date has multiple array than merge data into one the same key. Key should not be different. And All other which having same date with not repeated values also should have save with same procedure. Below is code which I've written.

```
$dups = $new_arr = array();
            foreach ($query->rows as $key => $val) {
                $new = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($val['create_date']));

                if (!isset($new_arr[$new])) {
                    $new_arr[$new] = $val;

                    //die;
                } else {
                    if (isset($dups[$new])) {
                       $dups[$new][] = $val;
                       //print_r($dups[$new]);
                      //echo "\n";
                    } else {
                       //$dups[$new] = array($val);
                       $dups[$new] = array($new_arr[$new], $value);
                    }
                }
            }
            //echo "<pre>";
            print_R($dups);
            die;
```

The code is returning only the data for repeated values and not returning data which are not repeating. Also keys are returning fine but the values are merging from another date. Any help will be appreciated.

Input Array Which we want to sort:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [loyalty_transcation_id] => 36
        [user_id] => 23
        [bill_copy_image_path] => 05082018_144348.jpg
        [create_date] => 2018-05-08 15:43:48
        [name] => Admin
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [loyalty_transcation_id] => 35
        [user_id] => 18
        [bill_copy_image_path] => 04052018_160009.jpg
        [create_date] => 2018-04-05 17:00:09
        [name] => gurpreet.singh@outlook.de
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [loyalty_transcation_id] => 33
        [user_id] => 58
        [bill_copy_image_path] => 03252018_182712.jpg
        [create_date] => 2018-03-25 19:27:12
        [name] => bernd koch
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [loyalty_transcation_id] => 32
        [user_id] => 57
        [bill_copy_image_path] => 03252018_160706.jpg
        [create_date] => 2018-03-25 17:07:06
        [name] => alex
    )
   )
```

Comment: Please provide expected output of data you pasted.

Comment: @Pyton please check edited code.

Comment: Ok but what is the input :)

Comment: added array at last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$responseArr = array();
foreach($inputArr as $input) {
    $dateKey = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($input['create_date']));
    if(!isset($responseArr[$dateKey])) {
        $responseArr[$dateKey] = array();
    }
    array_push($responseArr[$dateKey], $input);
}
```